# Android fingerprint on SDK<23

Tags: android, fingerprint

I have a project on Android with minSDK=17 and targetSDK=23. We have a fingerprint authentication in this project made using FingerprintManager class (it was added in SDK23). We added SDK version check, so we are not using anything related to fingerprint if SDK<23. But in older SDK versions app behaviour is unpredictable: on some versions app just crashing, on other -- fingerprint not working (so, it's ok).

My question:

1) Is it any good and easy-to-implement libraries for minSDK=17, that can recognize fingerprints?
2) How can I avoid app crashing in devices with SDK<23?
Crash error:

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager', referenced from method nl.intratuin.LoginActivity.loginByFingerprint
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   java.lang.VerifyError:
LoginActivity at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
```

---

Some new info: created HelloWorld fingerprint project using this tutorial:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial
Found the root of the problem:
FingerprintDemoActivity->cipherInit:

```
try {
    keyStore.load(null);
    SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
             null);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    return true;
} catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
    return false;
} catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException 
      | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
      | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
}
```

First catch block breacking whole app with error I mentioned above. Of course, I can just remove this catch (this exception extends InvalidKeyException, so it will be handled), and return false in case of any exceptions. Is it any better way?

Comment: "Is it any good and easy-to-implement libraries for minSDK=17, that can recognize fingerprints?" -- any pre-23 fingerprint support is manufacturer-specific. "How can I avoid app crashing in devices with SDK<23?" -- please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 14):

I think, I found acceptable solution: catch not KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException, but InvalidKeyException. Everything working fine this way. Still have no idea how this exception crashed whole app...

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me also..even when i used : if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M).. my app crashes on android 4.4- kitkat. so eventually the problem was in the initCipher method in the catches part  - see the following code (even though i m not suppose to get there as it targeted to M and above... very strange behaviour..) :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean initCipher() {
    try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
        mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        return true;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;

    }
}
```

apparently the order off the catches matter..so just make sure to write it as i mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

**Reason for  Crash:**

The `FingerprintManager`  class works with **Android version 23** and Higher.

If your app is using `FingerprintManager` class and runs on older version of Android then you will encounter this exception.

**Supporting older versions of Android:**

Use `FingerprintManagerCompat` instead of `FingerprintManager` if you are planning to support **Android <23**. The `FingerprintManagerCompat` class internally checks for the Android version and handle Authentication part with ease.

**How to Use it:**

- Replace `android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager` With `android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat`
- Replace `android.os.CancellationSignal` With  `android.support.v4.os.CancellationSignal`

See Sample Code

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/FingerPrint-Authentication-With-React-Native-Android/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/aproject/view/Fragments/FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.java

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a library created by afollestad called [digitus](https://github.com/evilcore/digitus).
This library can fall back to a password if fingerprints are not available.

Any devices prior to SDK 23 need to use their own separate device manufacturer based sdk.

Answer (score 1):

just follow android studio hint, it will be OK.

```
 try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(keyName, null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException
            | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyStoreException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of the question

> How can I avoid app crashing in devices with SDK<23?

This simplistic logic check will suffice:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) { 
   // Handle the mechanism where the SDK is older.
}else{
   // Handle the mechanism where the SDK is 23 or later.
}
```

Comment: Tried to do so, but anyway, my sdk 17 crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving all the fingerprint code to a helper class so that the classes related to the fingerprint code are not imported in the activity and by instantiating the helper class only when the SDK_INT is greater than 23 (In my case, as I'm supporting only Android 6+)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.Even when i used : if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M).. my app crashes on lower API's. I solved that as follow:
Replaced these codes:

```
      try {

            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                    null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException
                | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
```

with:

```
     try {

            keyStore.load(null);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SecretKey key = null;
        try {
            key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                    null);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
```